# Archimedean completeness of some fields

Tags: reference-request, nonstandard-analysis, ordered-fields

I need a reference (different from Hahn's 1907 paper) for the following result.

> **Theorem:** If $G$ is a totally ordered abelian group, then the field $\mathbb{R}((G))$ is archimedean complete.

- $\mathbb{R}((G))$ consists of all the functions $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
  $\{g\in G:f(g)\neq0\}$ is well-ordered.
- Let $E$ be an ordered field. Two nonzero elements $x,y\in E$ are *comparable* if there exist $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x|<m|y|$ and $|y|<n|x|$ (where $|a|$ is defined as $\max\{a,-a\}$).
- Let $E/ K$ be an extension of ordered fields, where the order on $E$ restricted to $K$ coincides with that of $K$. We say that $E$ is an *Archimedean extension of $K$* if for every $x\in E$, there exists $y\in K$ such that $x$ and $y$ are comparable in $E$.
- A field $K$ is *Archimedean complete* if it has no proper archimedean extension fields.

Does anyone know a good reference for the proof of this result? The more the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many such proofs in the literature. The completeness for Hahn fields follows from the completeness for Hahn groups, since every Hahn field is a Hahn group. For a simple proof of the latter, see pp. 862-863 of *Note on Hahn's Theorem on Ordered Abelian Groups*, A.H. Clifford, Proc. Am Math. Soc. 5 (1954), pp. 860-863. Many other references can be found in the following question of mine on Mathoverflo [Hahn's Embedding Theorem and the oldest open question in set theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128935/hahns-embedding-theorem-and-the-oldest-open-question-in-set-theory).

Comment: I understand the embedding theorem, but in the references there is not mention about the notion of Archimedean completeness.
If $K$ is an archimedean extension of $\mathbb{R}((G))$, then $K$ is of type $G$ (the group of Archimedean classes of $K$ is isomorphic to $G$). Thus, by the embedding theorem there exists an embedding $\theta$ from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}((G))$. But still can happen that $K$ is a proper extension of $\mathbb{R}((G))$. How can we discard that possibility? In general, this situation is possible. For example $K((x))$ can be embedded in $K((x^2))$ being a proper extension of it

Comment: @Chilote. You are mistaken. Look at the last paragraph on p. 862. It begins: "Theorem 3.2 (i.e. Hahn's Embedding Theorem) is beautifully adapted to the proof of Hahn's completeness theorem.... Hahn defines a complete ordered group to be an ordered group $G$ which does not admit a proper extension $H$ which is Archimedean relative to $G$....."

Comment: I have to admit I overlooked big part of that page. Thanks for the keen reference.