# Hausdorff's question on $\omega_1$-gap

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, open-problems, infinite-combinatorics

I read [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_most_important_open_problems_in_set_theory2) that the following problem of Hausdorff is apparently still open.

> Is there a maximal branch $C$ in the poset $\omega^\omega$ with the eventual domination order, such that $C$ has no $\omega_1$-gap.

My questions concerning the above problem are:

1. What is its current status?
2. What are the consequences of its solution? negative, independence or positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is solved. See

[Francisco Kibedi: Maximal Saturated Linear Orders](http://settheory.mathtalks.org/francisco-kibedi-maximal-saturated-linear-orders/)

See also Kibedi's PhD thesis

[Maximal Saturated Linear Orders](https://yorkspace.library.yorku.ca/xmlui/handle/10315/32107).

---

The problem is independence of ZFC. The question asks "is there a pantachy containing no $(\omega_1, \omega_1^*)$-gap?". See Kanovei's answer given in [Hahn's Embedding Theorem and the oldest open question in set theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128935/hahns-embedding-theorem-and-the-oldest-open-question-in-set-theory).

Now as the author explains, CH implies a no answer to the above equivalent question (known to Hausdorff). The author shows the consistency of the statement.

Comment: I don't see how it implies that.

Comment: You make us have to go to the link just to find out if the answer is yes or no or maybe?

Comment: The abstract is not exhaustively clear. The key result is formulated as Con(ZFC + ¬CH + ∃ a maximal saturated linear order of size continuum in the space of real-valued sequences partially ordered by eventual domination), where `saturated' lacks the cardinal parameter of saturation, while `of size continuum' looks strange since the whole poset is of cardinality c. Also, there is no indication how the key result implies a required gapless pantachy.

Comment: I have just recognized that the reference to `See also Kibedi's PhD thesis

Maximal Saturated Linear Orders.' does not work

Comment: @VladimirKanovei It works but possibly you need to use some anti-filter program (the same is for me).

Comment: Yes it happens to work

Comment: And Theorem 1.2.1 claims Con(ZFC + non-CH + there is a pantachie with no (w_1; w_1)-gaps), by means of a ccc forcing, based on an earlier work of Laver