# Hahn’s theorem on ordered fields

Tags: reference-request, fields, non-archimedean-fields

There is a theorem attributed to Hahn that every ordered field $F$ containing $\mathbb R$ is a subfield of a formal power series field $\mathbb R[[X^\Gamma]]$, where $\Gamma$ is an ordered abelian group.  Can you give a nice reference in English for a proof of this theorem?  Or if it is not too hard, please sketch a proof below.

Comment: [MacLane - The universality of formal power-series fields](https://doi.org/10.1090%2Fs0002-9904-1939-07110-3) proves a related fact with $\mathbb C$ in place of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This theorem, which extends Hahn's embedding theorem for ordered abelian groups to ordered fields, has a complicated history that makes it difficult to attribute it to any single author. However, by the early 1950s, as a result of the work of Kaplansky (1942), it appears to have assumed the status of a ``folk theorem'' among knowledgeable field theorists, with numerous proofs published thereafter. For an in-depth history of the embedding theorem along with numerous references to proofs, see my paper:

*Hahn’s Über die Nichtarchimedischen Grössensysteme and the Development of the Modern Theory of Magnitudes and Numbers to Measure Them*. In:**From Dedekind to Gödel: Essays on the Development of the Foundations of Mathematics**, edited by J. Hintikka, Kluwer Academic Publishers, Dordrecht, 1995, pp. 165-213.

[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325019391_Hahn's_Uber](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325019391_Hahn%27s_Uber)

Edit:

Strictly speaking, the theorem I am referring to is much deeper than the embedding theorem stated in the question, though I suspect it is the one that is intended. A weak formulation of the ordered-field-theoretic generalization of Hahn's Embedding Theorem asserts: If $K$ is an ordered field and $\Gamma$ is its ordered Abelian group of Archimedean classes, then there is an embedding of $K$ into the Hahn field $\mathbb{R}[[X^\Gamma ]]$. For increasingly stronger versions of the theorem, see the paper cited above.

Comment: Is it correct to say that what you call a “Hahn embedding” in the paper is a highly nonconstructive object?  If so, are there any results attempting to quantify how many such distinct representations of an ordered field $K$ exist?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Yes, as with Hahn's classical embedding theorem for ordered Abelian groups, one makes use of the axiom of choice to prove the analogous embedding theorem for ordered fields. As I mentioned in an earlier post (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128935/hahns-embedding-theorem-and-the-oldest-open-question-in-set-theory), it is an open question if Hahn's theorem is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. The same question can also be raised for the embedding theorem for ordered fields.

Comment: Is there any canonical notion of a decomposition of a field element into “components” in various Archimedean classes? Obviously there is the Archimedean class of the element itself, but what about in smaller classes? The representation in a Hahn field gives a presentation as a vector, but can we recover those coordinates in some natural way as we can in Hilbert spaces?

Comment: There is a canonical decomposition for surreal numbers--the normal forms, or Conway names as I call them--but that makes use of the simplicity hierarchy. Without the simplicity hierarchy, the decomposition depends on various selections. For the surreal case, see e.g. my "Number systems with simplicity hierarchies: a generalization of Conway's theory of surreal numbers", J Sym Log 66 (2001), pp. 1231-1258.  And for the classical case, see e.g. Mourgues and Ressayre "Every real closed field has an integer part", J. Sym Log 58 (1993),  pp. 641-647.